# Remove quote from a jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm making an Ajax request in a Rails app and I hava a little problem when I want to recover variable.

Let say that the data I pass to the Ajax request looks like this

```
var dataAll = ({dataForKey: dataItemID});
```

And let say that the two seconds variable are recovered like this

```
var dataForKey = '<%= feed_item.class.to_s.foreign_key %>';
var dataItemID = '<%= feed_item.id %>';
```

Imagine that `feed_item.class.to_s.foreign_key` returns `photo`. So, `dataForKey` value's is `'photo'`.

But, I need `dataForKey` to be `photo` and not `'photo'` and I can't say

```
var dataForKey = <%= feed_item.class.to_s.foreign_key %>;
```

Because jQuery looks for a variable called `photo`...

So, let's summarize it : how can I remove the quote from `dataForKey` ?

Comment: "So, dataForKey value's is 'photo'" Is that really true? Doesn't JavaScript use the quote to delimit the string and not save it in the value? If jQuery is looking for a variable photo and you don't want it to then don't you actually need the quote generated?

Comment: i don't get what you want photo but not variable photo, want string photo but not 'photo'.. by removing quotes would be syntax error so what you want?

Comment: is photo a variable declared in javascript ? Not sure i understand, does it return " ' photo ' " ? or the string 'photo' ?

Comment: post the source not the server code to give better idea what problem is

Comment: The problem is that you can't use a variable to act as the key in an object, because the syntax `{ dataForKey : dataItemID }` is valid and creates an object with a property called `dataForKey`, rather than an object with a property called whatever the value of the `dataForKey` variable is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than saving the name of the key into a variable, just output it directly:

```
var dataItemID = '<%= feed_item.id %>';
var dataAll = ({<%= feed_item.class.to_s.foreign_key %>: dataItemID});
```

Or, create your object and set the values separately:

```
var dataForKey = '<%= feed_item.class.to_s.foreign_key %>';
var dataItemID = '<%= feed_item.id %>';
var dataAll = {};
dataAll[dataForKey] = dataItemID;
```

Comment: Yeah, the first version is what I was doing and it worked fine. But I'm putting it in an external JS file and your second proposition works ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use `eval`:

```
var dataForKey = eval('<%= feed_item.class.to_s.foreign_key %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataForKey = dataForKey.replace("'", "");
```